# What does the angle between plane of earth's orbit and ecliptic vary between?

Tags: orbit, earth

What does the angle between the plane of the earth's orbit and the ecliptic (now about 23.5 degrees) vary between, and over what time scale?

Comment: I think you mean the plane of Earth's equator and the ecliptic.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, it is zero; the ecliptic *is* the plane of earth's orbit (or rather, the inverse: the path the Sun seems to follow along the sky).

But you're probably looking for variations in the [axial tilt of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt#Earth). There's a lot of formulas in the article, and on the (astronomically speaking) short timescale of a few million years, it oscillates between 22 and 24.5 degrees with a period of about 41,000 years. See the graph below, the red dot is the year 2000:

[image]

<sub>(picture by Tfr000 on Wikipedia, data from Laskar (1986))</sub>